# How to fix this output bug on a program that checks how many times an element of an array is contained in another array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I was doing a little python program to check how many times elements of an array are contained in another array, and, once I find the answer I add then into a list of intengers, which contains all their accurances. Example of input :

```
Number of elements of the first array : 4
Number of elements of the second array : 3

elements of the first array : aba baba aba xzxb
elements of the second array : aba xzxb ab


Ouput : 2 0 0
```

But the output is *incorrect*, because I was expecting  `2 1 0`. I already debugged the program, but I didn't find what is cousing this behaviour.

here is my code :

```
nElemL1 = int(input("Insert the number of elements of the first array\n"))
nElemL2 = int(input("Insert the number of elements of the second array\n"))

list1 =[]
list2 = []

print("Insert the elements of the first array\n")
for i in range (nElemL1) :
    someElement = input()
    list1.append(someElement)

print("Insert the elements of the second array\n")
for i in range (nElemL2) :
    someElement = input()
    list2.append(someElement)

listCounts =[]

for j in range (nElemL2) :
    counti = 0
    for i in range (nElemL1) :
        if i == (nElemL1-1) :
            if list2[j] == list1[i] :
                counti = counti+1
            listCounts.append(counti)
        elif list2[j] == list1[i] :
            counti = counti+1

print ("\n\nAnswers\n\n")
for i in listCounts :
    print (i)
```

*Notes:*

The examples of the inputs were vertical, like any other commom python terminal aplication, I just made them horizontal for a better comprehension.

This python aplication was just a demo to check if the logic of the c++ version of the code is fine, so if you do not use function in python that are equivalent to the ones contained in the  and  library, like `find` our `count` I would be very gratefull, because I did not understood them pretty well yet.

Comment: You wrote a python code to debug a c++ code, but that python code doesn't work as expected so you're asking how to fix it? Why not ask about the c++ code in the first place?

Comment: Because I did not make the c++ program yet